# Render full header from API

Tags: magento2.2, header, renderer

I need to pass the whole header to another website through an API.

Do not ask why, this is the task.

I asked some help from one of my colleague, he suggest me to create a controller, what has a layout and block only with header, get it from API with `curl` or `file_get_contents` (does not matter).

Somehow I feel this is a workaround.

Does anybody do like this, is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: there are magento wrapper classes for the methods you mentioned. use them instead